# What is the 'standard' content of .gitignore for an iPhone (Xcode) project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, version-control, gitignore

What is considered the 'standard' content of .gitignore file for an iPhone (Xcode) project?

PS: not sure if this needs to be a CW.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
build/
.DS_Store
**/*.pbxuser
*.mode2v3
*.mode1v3
**/*.perspectivev*
```

This is a good start.

updated with Dave's suggestions.

Comment: +1 I usually do `**/*.pbxuser`, and I also add `**/*.perspectivev*`

Answer (score 10):

You should also exclude `xcworkspace` and `xcuserdata` in xcode 4.2. So here is a complete list which one should ignore for iOS projects

```
# Exclude the build directory
build/*

# Exclude temp nibs and swap files
*~.nib
*.swp

# Exclude OS X folder attributes
.DS_Store

# Exclude user-specific XCode 3 and 4 files
*.mode1
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*.pbxuser
*.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
```

Comment: xcworkspace isn't ignored now..https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore

Answer (score 6):

From the GitHub `gitignore` project, as of today:

```
# Xcode
.DS_Store
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
```

Source: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore