# xcodeproj under version control

Tags: xcode, version-control

What are the best practices while including a Xcode project under version control.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12817011/843660

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is what is in my [Global](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files) `.gitignore` file which you can see as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/708713) on GitHub, but the Xcode list can be applied to other systems

```
# Mac OS X
*.DS_Store

# Xcode
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/

# Generated files
*.o
*.pyc

#Python modules
MANIFEST
dist/
build/

# Backup files
*~.nib
\#*#
.#*
```

Comment: I'd remove the "Pyhon modules" part of this, since it's probably not relevant to many XCode projects

Comment: It's __My__ .gitignore, which has more than Xcode specific settings.

Answer (score 8):

Check in `project.pbxproj`, ignore the user specific files.

Include shared components and third party libraries as project dependencies using submodules/externals/whatever your VCS supports instead of manually copying static library binaries without any history.

You will get merge conflicts in the `project.pbxproj`, be prepared to deal with this and try to minimize the difficulty of resolving them.

- Have a consistent structure for where files should be on disk and how that maps to groups in Xcode.
- Sort the resources included in your build targets and the order of resources within your project's groups. I really need to write a script to do this for me because it is so much easier to identify the cause of a merge conflict when you don't have to diff two random sets of files. It also avoids many merge conflicts as you're less likely to have multiple developers all appending new resources to the bottom of a list.

Check in early and often.

Answer (score 2):

In my project I have `Project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` in version control and leave out the `User.mode1v3` and `User.pbxuser` files.

project.pbxproj seems to hold the metadata for the project, such as where the files are located and what the build settings are.

The user files would have things like what files are opened, where the cursor is, etc.

You can also refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) question for what files some people have chosen to ignore.