# Bitbucket + Xcode Not Showing Proper Project

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket, repository

I've just setup bitbucket git repo with Xcode. I had a local repo on my MacBook Pro which I ported to BitBucket. Then on my new iMac I added the repo and it cloned it. In the project folder all the files are there, iPhone storyboard, iPad storyboard etc etc but when I open the project file in Xcode, either by opening in Xcode or by clicking the project file it opens a project that is essentially blank with just iPhone storyboard and project name.

No idea why this is happening as full project is on iMac

EDIT:

It's now working on my iMac but the version on my MacBook will never Push as it says there is uncommited changes but it's always the same file `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` No matter how many times I commit it seems to think it still has uncommited changes.

Comment: Have you checked out the current branch?

Comment: There is only one branch Master as I've only just added this

Comment: Try checking out Master. I had a problem similar to this and it worked for me.

Comment: I've just checked and it appears the project hasn't created proper. The project file is wrong, being a basic project file and there is some txt files missing

Comment: Oh I had that problem too. I used SourceTree to add it to the repository ignore list - this file is in constant flux because it holds userstate data, it doesn't need to be part of the repository (and it wouldn't make any difference on other macs anyway as it's saved in a folder specific to your username).

Answer (score 0):

There are some files that you can safely ignore in git. `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` is one of them. There's a [great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4684751/459116) that lists others.