# Xcode projects -- what is a "perspectivev3 file"

Tags: xcode

When I look at the package of one of my projects, I sometimes see one of these.  What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the file where XCode saves the preferences of your "perspective". 
Where you windows are, if your console is open, where it is on the screen.
Which groups are open in the side bar etc.
Basically everything you need that xcode looks the same when you open it next time.

There is another file name `username.pbxuser`. Xcode stores for example the code bookmarks in it.

You don't need them to compile the project. And you should not put them into version control either.

Answer (score 0):

Those are files that Xcode creates.  They are user-specific project settings.  No need to worry about them.

Edit: Based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects/49488#49488) question, I would add these to your .gitignore/.hgignore:

```
.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib

build/

*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
```

Comment: Well, I'm using Mercurial to share with other people; should I add it to my repository?  or to .hgignore?