# iPhone : How do I add existing project in "git local repository"?

Tags: git

I have existing project and I want to add it in "git local repository".

How can I do that ?

Comment: You can push the changes from command line to the repository.

Comment: I don't know about command line. Can you please help me?

Comment: This has nothing to do with any of the tags you've used. Can you please update your post to remove the iPhone/Obj-C related tags and use git ones instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the `Terminal` and go to your project directory – the one with `*.xcodeproj`.

1. Type `git init .` to initialize a Git repository there.
2. Now you don't want all the files under source control, so Git allows you to ignore some of them by including them in a file `.gitignore`. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) to find out
3. Open the project and your task is done. However it would be better to head to the Organizer Window and do a commit of all the files.

Now your project is backed by a git repository.

Comment: But it will create user defined repository. I want to allow xcode4 to handle my repository automatically. If you remember that in xcode4 if you have checked for "git local repository". It will show source safe when you select your project.

Comment: Can you elaborate automatically? I don't think there is a difference in a way Xcode 4 treats a user created repository and an Xcode-generated repository.

Comment: Can find few more steps at following link: Adding Git to an existing Xcode project (http://noblevelop.com/adding-git-to-an-existing-xcode-project/)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, assuming you've got git installed. http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/creating-local-git-repositories-yeah-its-that-simple/.