# For a Cocoa app, what files should be under version control?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, git, version-control

I forgot to check the box in Xcode to create a git repository for my Cocoa application. So which files should I manually add to version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `.gitignore` for XCode4 project (as detailled in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects), or in this [GitHub XCode addon](https://github.com/tbarbe/Xcode-Git-User-Script)), and add everything else.

Comment: Thank you, that question is exactly what I was looking for. I had searched, but not come across it. Going to mark to close this question.

Comment: @rubergly: the situation being slightly different, it can be helpful to others being in that same situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete list of files to ignore, see [this](https://github.com/oscardelben/cocoa-gitignore).