# Source control in XCode is a nightmare - can anyone offer advice?

Tags: ios, git, version-control, xcode4

Using Git with Xcode (4.3) is a real nightmare.

Here's a scenario...

I want to add a new feature, so I create a new topic branch.

I add my new feature and I'm ready to commit, rebase and merge...

I commit my changes - fine.

I jump back to master to pull changes (in case someone else has updated the code).
  Suddenly I get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
myProject/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/Bodacious.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

huh? I just committed.

Xcode likes to change my `project.xcworkspace` files every other second which makes it almost impossible to make clean, atomic commits.

What's more, if I do commit the changes in `project.xcworkspace` and quickly jump back to another branch (in order to merge into Master for example) then Xcode will complain that the files have changed and probably crash too.

From what I gather, [I can't add these files to my `.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026429/should-i-git-ignore-xcodeproject-project-pbxproj-file) either.

Do I have to accept that a concise and orderly git strategy is not possible with Xcode, close Xcode before doing any Git management, or is there another option available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just add those files to my `.gitignore` file. There is no need to share them with other developers.

So I have:

```
*.xcworkspace
```

In .gitignore

Note that the stackoverflow question you linked to says to not exclude `project.pbxproj`, but it doesn't say not to exclude `*.xcworkspace`.

However, I'm not using the workspace feature at this time. If you do use the workspace feature you may want to include those files, but ignore the `xcuserdata` files.

Comment: @VanDuTran you could specifically put `*.xcscheme` in your .gitignore file, but it is probably better just to put `xcuserdata` in the .gitignore file to ignore all user-specific data.

Answer (score 2):

The question you linked was only referring to the `xcodeproject/project.pbxproj` file. You should be able to safely `.gitignore` the other files.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't push your commit just because `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` has been modified, here's a quick fix:

1. Open the Organizer, go to Repositories, copy your the commit's code (something like `f01a2147218d by username`)
2. Open the terminal, go to your project's folder, do `git reset --hard f01a2147218d`
3. Push the commit!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on Xcode 5.1:

1. Commit and push your changes for the branch you're on.
2. Go to Xcode > Source Control > Discard all changes (should only discard the workspace problem)
3. Checkout the branch that you want and merge or whatever you're trying to do.

Note: if you wait too long or do anything in Xcode before checking out the new branch, you might have to discard changes again