# git - tried to merge, but got a conflict in xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Tags: xcode, git

When I do git status now, I get this as part of the results

```
#   both modified:      BusinessPlan.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

This is kind of an important file because Apple's xCode uses it to open the whole project. I am not even sure it should be in git.  Should it?

How can I resolve this? Should this file not be committed? I think I might have gotten changes from other developers. How can I clean it up and what is the way to work with this kind of a file long-term?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004135/how-to-merge-conflicts-file-project-pbxproj-in-xcode-use-svn

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In order to get Git and Xcode to play together nicely, you need to tell Git to ignore a handful of the extraneous files Xcode uses.

Create a file called `.gitignore` in the root folder of your project, and include this text:

```
# files created by Xcode 3 or older
*.pbxuser
*.mode1
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
*.xcclassmodel/
# files created by Xcode 4
xcuserdata/
# build products
*.build/
build/
DerivedData/
# Misc
.svn
.DS_Store
```

This will instruct Git to ignore all of the files that will cause problems.

Taken from Beanstalk page on [Setting up Git with XCode 4](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/95580-setting-up-git-with-xcode-4).

Comment: Downvoted this answer: `*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` is not in the `.gitignore` file, and this file definitely should not be ignored by `git`.

Comment: I have had success with https://github.com/simonwagner/mergepbx for merging the project file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am afraid you have to merge this file. In fact, in the most case, it can be done correctly and automatically. You don't need to merge it yourself.

ps: about strategy of using git for iOS project, there is quite a lot discussion exist. Google something like [iOS gitignore](https://www.google.com/#hl=fr&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=ios+gitignore&oq=ios+git&gs_l=hp.3.3.0j0i30l3.1033.2348.0.5965.7.7.0.0.0.0.194.764.4j3.7.0...0.0...1c.1.ZGF0JSdFgNY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41642243,d.d2k&fp=215dc585e082e8a3&biw=1294&bih=738), than you can find [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) or [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026429/should-i-git-ignore-xcodeproject-project-pbxproj-file), etc ...