# git checkout fails with error - Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: xcode, git

I've got this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Crashlytics
    Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Crashlytics.h
    Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist
    Crashlytics.framework/run
    <my project name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Some questions:

1. I had a clean code base a few moments ago (I'd checked out master). It seems when I run Xcode it creates some locally changed Crashlytics files. How do I stop this from happening?
2. Why has my pbxproj changed? Is it something to do with the Crashlytics code?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of help, I should first state that I'm not familiar with *xcode* but rather familiar with *git* so you should not take my response definitely right. 
In general, you can add those entries to the *.gitignore* file if you do not want them to be tracked by git.

Meanwhile, I don't advice ignoring the *.pbxproj* descriptor as stated in [this thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026488/2106516).

Concerning the other generated files, they may have been generated when you compiled or run some task on your project.