# xcode 4 not cooperating with git

Tags: xcode, git

I'm seeing some strange behavior with Xcode 4 and git.

1. Create a new project
2. Right click on files - choose source control then commit.  Add a comment.
3. Choose source control then push from the file menu.
4. Xcode returns an error complaining about uncommitted changes?!?

Calling `git status` from the command line, I can see that some of the internal userdata files are not committed.  Shouldn't Xcode know to either skip or include those?  There is **no indication** in Xcode that there are any uncommitted files.  The only way to find them is from the command line.

One thought would be to manually create a .gitignore file, but I would assume that Xcode handles all that internally.

Did I just stumble onto a bug, or is there some standard step that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Xcode changes the xcuserdata files every time you do something in the Xcode GUI. So, you need to Push immediately after you commit, otherwise you'll either need to commit again (which is wasteful) or push from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a bug is in the eyes of the beholder, isn't it. Yes, you need to [Setup your git ignores for xcode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects)