# Developing an iphone app using git. Files that must not be shared?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, gitignore

I'm developing iphone apps with a friends. We are sharing the code with git but we are facing some problems for instance when one add some new file (git add, git commit, git push) the other one can not see them in xcode and needs to copy them from filesystem.

What are the file to share on top of the source code ?
What are the file not to share (I'm thinking of files linked to xcodeproj, xcuserdata, ...) ?

Comment: Possibly related (although not exact duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` file should look somewhat like this:

```
.DS_Store
build/
*.pbxuser
xcuserdata/
```

Everything else contained in your project folder (sources, resources, etc...) can and should be shared. So yes, do share the `xxx.xcodeproj`- or even `xxx.xcworkspace`- folder or else your coworkers won't get updated versions of your project, possibly including new files to build.

The drafted .gitignore will prevent sharing of the .DS_Store, build-results, Xcode 3.x user-specific workspace settings and the Xcode 4.x user-specific workspace settings.

As mentioned by Tamas, you may actually just copy the mercurial pattern from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) and enhance it by `xcuserdata/` as drafted above to update it towards an Xcode 4.x compatible pattern.

Comment: is .gitignore a best alternative to .git/exclude ?

Comment: @Luc yes it is because it allows you to share that exclusion list via git itself (just add it as well).