# Naive Git setup, Is it possible to untrack files which are listed on my .gitignore?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, git, gitignore

I have made a naive mistake while setting up my project. We are 3 developers working on one remote repository. While setting up git we never thought that Xcode would produce non-development files and push them to our remote repo. Now once I learnt after crash and burn I made a `.gitignore` file.

.gitignore looks like this, please do let me know if I should edit this too. (File credit goes too : [This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) answer given by Abizem)

```
# Mac OS X
*.DS_Store

# Xcode
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/
```

But now question is there any possibilities that I can untrack all of those listed files from our source control?

or

Can I list all tracked files with their path and later I know a painful way to remove one by one with,

```
git rm --cached 'file path'
```

Comment: If you aren't that far along into the project you might just want to nuke the repository (just the .git repository, not the files!) and set it up again.

Comment: :( we have been committing for 15 to 20 days and it's a lot of files

Comment: Yeah, I understand how that goes. You wouldn't lose the files though, just the commit history.

Comment: Maybe this to list the files: git ls-files -i --exclude-standard, xargs for the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something I've done a few times in these situations, is move all of the files in the repository somewhere else on the filesystem (**except** .gitignore), then run:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Remove all files"
```

Then add your files back in and run the following:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Re-add files"
```

This second add & commit will adhere to your gitignore file.