# do .xcodeproj files manage files relatively

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a simple iOS app am going to start a new app using it as a template. The .xcodeproj directory isn't maintained in Git for things like xcuserdata. Is it possible I can just clone the repository and physically copy the .xcodeproj directory into the new location? Are all the file paths relative or will this strategy cause problems? I was told by friend to not keep the .xcodeproj in Git (although he knew that it was a small project). Is this a bad idea?

thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem having an Xcode project into git. Just make sure that you properly [ignore some of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects).

For the paths, Xcode projects can have both relative and absolute paths. It's your responsibility to ensure you are only using relative paths but don't worry it's easy.