# Git ignore file for Xcode 4 projects

Tags: ios, xcode, git, ios5, xcode4.3

Which files are better to ignore in git for an Xcode 4(.3.2)? This older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) addresses the same issue but I find my structure to be different so I assume it's about an older version of Xcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are git ignore files for basicly every language including Xcode : [Github - git ignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

For me it is working like a charm. Here is the content of the Objective-C.gitignore

```
# Xcode
build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
```

Comment: What about the schemes? They are in xcuserdata. Don't you track them?

Comment: @david since I do not use schemes other than the standard one and I am a sole developer this is not relevant for me - if you care about schemes just remove the xcuserdata line above.

Comment: Even though this is old I thought i should chime in on @Pfitz last statement. Even though you are a sole developer for a project, schemas are still important. Especially if you have different environments when connecting to a url. You can easily create a macro for each and every scheme like DEV, PROD and all you have to do is switch the schema to point to that server. Otherwise your going to have to manually change the url for dev and prod which is prone to user error

Answer (score 11):

This is what we use:

```
#xcode Noise
build/*
*.pbxuser
*.mode2v3
*.mode1v3
*.xcworkspace
xcuserdata

# OSX Noise
.DS_Store
profile
*~
*.lock
*.DS_Store
*.swp
*.out
```

Answer (score 5):

Existing answers are good. I just want to leave a note for people who are using `CocoaPods` to manage libraries. Besides the `xcworkspace` generated by CocoaPods, you should also ignore `Pods/` directory:

```
Pods/*
```

every developer should do `pod install` on their own machine separately. otherwise, they may face many environment issues.

Comment: You should not ignore Podfile.lock. That is used to ensure that everyone on a particular commit is looking at the same set of Pod files. http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html under "What is a Podfile.lock"

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the solution from the question you linked with a few changes. I think it has a really nice solution for ignoring unnecessary project files

```
#OS junk files
[Tt]humbs.db
*.DS_Store
*.bak*

#Xcode files
#This ignores everything inside a *.xcodeproj except the project.pbxproj
*.xcodeproj/
!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
*.log
xcuserdata

#Project files
[Bb]uild/

#Version control files
.svn
*.orig
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally ignore the following

- /ProjectPath/project.xcodeproj/xcuserdata
- /ProjectPath/project.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace

And some hidden files like

- /ProjectPath/.DS_Store