# XCode developer data

Tags: ios, xcode4

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) covers recommendations for a .gitignore file for Xcode projects.  But I have a simpler question.

My developer keys show up in Xcode.  I just want to know if I share an Xcode project, if my developer data will somehow attach itself with the project.  (I realize there's a whole painful process involving private keys etc, but I don't want any "pieces" of my apple developer acct shared)

Specifically, I am looking at the **Code Signing Identity** field, which says "currently matches 'iPhone Developer: Me (then some string like `H831JA8U2JIOA`).

Will the **Code Signing Identity** field reassign itself when opened on another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click where it says "currently matches 'iPhone Developer..." and verify that the checked option is under the "Automatic Profile Selector" heading. If it is, your personal info shouldn't be in the Xcode project. You can verify this further by searching the PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file for occurrences of your information.

For further confirmation, you can grep your project directory with `grep -ilR SIGNING_IDENTITY_HERE *` which should reveal any occurrences of the signing identity. You can cross-reference this output with the files ignored by git to assess your risk.

Comment: Yep, it just says `"CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "iPhone Developer";`, which must mean my information is _not_ attached in the file, but Xcode must actually look it up in some other Xcode data file (not the `.pbxproj`)

Comment: I think it just looks for an identity in the system keychain, not another Xcode file.

Answer (score 1):

The `Code Signing Identity` is defined in YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj, you could search the info with `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` as keyword, that file(project.pbxproj) could not be ignored by git.

So, if the another computer has the same iOS Provisioning Profiles, it will reassign automatically.