# Xcode .git ignore

Tags: ios, xcode, git, gitignore

My question is should you ignore the debugger folder and the Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist file. Or should the files be committed as well.

Is there a standard Xcode 5 git ignore file like the one listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) but for Xcode 5. I like this one because its comments explains every ignore file in detail for people who aren't as advanced like myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should Xcode 5 gitignore file include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939421/what-should-xcode-5-gitignore-file-include)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a large debug/build folder in the same directory I would ignore that because it should just be full of one time build files that you definitely don't need to keep around. I assume that Breakpoints file stores all information on how you've used breakpoints in the project which I would definitely commit.

Comment: Why definitely commit breakpoints file? There is a tradeoff here isn't there? If it is your own project then maybe you care to recreate breakpoint state; however, if others are working on the same code they may not want your breakpoints info

Comment: You can have breakpoints either shared or personal. And then you can commit just the shared ones. So if you want to share any common breakpoints for your project you can make the decision at that point, and if you don't share any that file won't exist.

Comment: Fair enough. That's a good idea

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Gitignore files for Xcode 5 project should look like this:

```
# Xcode
.DS_Store
#build file
build/
#personal settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
#xcode state
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
```