# What should be in my gitignore for Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, git, swift, gitignore

With **Xcode 7** finally released I was wondering what an appropriate setting for `.gitignore` was for Xcode projects in the new version, and whether the same settings that were applicable in **XCODE 6** still apply.

**NOTE** This is **XCODE 7 Specific**.  *There are various answers for other version of XCODE but I am unaware if 7 adds any new files or types that should be added to the .gitignore.*

Comment: Look for Github gitignore file
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore

Comment: This is an Xcode 7 specific question.  That post you reference is for a different version of Xcode.

Comment: crosscode's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27745571/4515489 has useful info about Xcode 6 (much simpler than Xcode 4), but there still may be changes between 6 & 7, so I agree this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the [one](https://github.com/mdippery/blackout/blob/master/.gitignore) I tend to use:

```
.DS_Store
build
*.xcodeproj/*
!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

That will ignore `.DS_Store` files, the `build` directory, and everything in `.xcodeproj` files except the file that actually contains the project's settings. If you have shared schemes, you can also add

```
!*.xcodeproj/xcshareddata
```

as show [here](https://github.com/mdippery/bucknellbug/blob/master/.gitignore).

Comment: I wouldn't ignore `*.xcodeproj`, rather ignore `xcuserdata`.

Comment: @Arkku: `project.pbxproj` and `xcshareddata` (possibly) are really the only files in the a `.xcodeproj` that _need_ to be tracked.

Comment: True at the moment (unless it contains workspaces?), but I would rather blacklist than whitelist here, since a) currently it's simpler that way, and b) the contents of `.xcodeproj` could change without notice as it is a proprietary format…