# .xccheckout had a tree conflict

Tags: git, version-control, xcode5, bitbucket, shared-data

Using Xcode 5.x and Git, we did a commit on this file: MyProjectName.xccheckout.  We then pushed this commit to our central repo.  Now, when someone else on the team does a Pull we get the error: "MyProjectName.xccheckout had a tree conflict."

There are several posts on this topic and appears the correct thing to do is to commit this file.  But now that we've done this, how do we handle the conflict?

This post [Should *.xccheckout files in Xcode5 be ignored under VCS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340453/should-xccheckout-files-in-xcode5-be-ignored-under-vcs) covers the same issue but don't see how they resolved the conflict.

- Update: I manually merged the changes from the central repo down to my local copy, then tried to do the Pull again but got the same error.  I've also noticed the values in this file change from time to time but not sure what's causing that.
- Update: Here's an example of the value that's changing in the file:
  IDESourceControlProjectIdentifier
  3869BFC7-FD51-432F-A70B-CE2ADC0CDF1F

Comment: "tree conflict" sounds like `svn` and not `git`...

Comment: not svn, using git and bitbucket

Answer (score 4):

Have you try to remove this file from git by

```
rm YourProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/YourProjectName.xccheckout
```

Next step is to commit

```
git commit -m "remove YourProjectName.xccheckout"
```

Push again from machine where this file was tracked first.

This action will delete .xccheckout from repo and other team members can pull.

Comment: We had already removed the file from the repo.  Based on other threads related to this topic, we're still wondering if we should even be trying to keep this file under source control.  Still can't find a way around the 'tree conflict' error.

Comment: This worked for me. Just delete/check out fresh branches (make sure no merge in progress hang ups) and then delete the appropriate xccheckout file, commit, perform the merge and it works fine.

Comment: isn't it `git rm`, not `rm`?