# Xcode 7: ignore .xcscmblueprint in repository?

Tags: xcode, repository, gitignore, xcode7

I noticed that Xcode 7 creates a new `.xcscmblueprint` file in the `xcshareddata` folder. Will it be always auto generated? Should this file be added to the ignore list of the repository, or should it be checked in into repository?

Xcode 6 has the `.xccheckout` file, I've always gitignore'd that file.

Comment: Apparently not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19260712/6309 or https://gist.github.com/tokorom/5829394

Comment: what does the discussion about `.xcceckout` gotta do with anything? ie in both the OP's question as well as the comment above?

Comment: They are similar in content.

Comment: FYI, VonC's `apparently not` comment means, "Apparently you should NOT ignore .xcscmblueprint and here is why" and his link mentions why.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm gitignoring them, for exactly the same reason as .xccheckout.

GitHub's maintained .gitignore added that too, for both Objective-C and Swift.  https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's a great argument. I'm going to adopt Github's gitignore template as well. BTW here's the direct link to the Swift gitignore template: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore

Comment: Today, it was also added to default Xcode .gitignore https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1546

Comment: Today, it was removed from default Xcode .gitignore, and removed for Objective-C and Swift as well: https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1686

Comment: @AlexZavatone Yup, everything in xcshareddata should never be ignored… yet nobody seems to understand that…

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends. Just like @Ewan Mellor said the reason for ignore `.xcscmblueprint` is same with it for `.xccheckout`.

But whether ignore `.xccheckout` depends on your project . If you are using single project there is no need. If you are using workspace committing  xccheckout file is need. For more the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19260712/4383896) @Chris Hanson published is feed your need.

Back to the question. The content of the `xcscmblueprint` contains the main information about your project.
[image]

And I'm not sure it will change in the future. As the same reason for `xccheckout` I would like to commit this file.

Comment: You should always .gitignore .xccheckout. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340453/should-xccheckout-files-in-xcode5-be-ignored-under-vcs/19260712#comment29617170_19260712: "It looks like xccheckout contains keys and names which are specific to each developer's machine... As soon as I run xcode it changes some keys in the file [...]. If this file is supposed to be shared, then Apple have done a pretty poor job."

Answer (score 1):

The files seems to contain information pertaining to your source code repository. I think the "SCM" part of the filename stands for "Source Code Management". When looking at the one in my project, it indeed contains information about the GitHub repository that my XCode projects it (and also the git submodules that my repository uses, that's neat!). Of course, it also contains hashes so one could wonder if they are stable across developer, but I'd bet they are.

For that reason, I back up the advice given in many comments. You DO want to version this file.