# Xcode 5 - How to use source control with a workspace

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode5, xcode-workspace

I've created myself a Xcode 5 workspace and added 2 projects into it. The first project is a Mac OS X `Cocoa Application` and the second is an `External Build System`.

When creating the projects I checked the option so it would create a git repository for each. Then, I've tried looking at the menu item ***Source Control*** and every sub item was grayed out except ***Check Out ...*** which is not what I want to do. I wish to add the files to the repo.

How can use source control in Xcode 5 with a workspace?

---

**Edit:** I've tried to create the projects without the git source control option and creating the git repositories manually from the Terminal. Sadly, Xcode is not detecting them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution to my problem.

I created the workspace with the projects inside without any source control options. Then, I manually created a single git repo inside my source folder by doing the following in the Terminal.

```
cd /path-to-my-source-code/.git
git init
git add .
```

After, I added a .gitignore file inside the .git folder as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021580/209824.

The final step was to restart Xcode.