# gitignore not ignoring file

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

No matter what I put in `.gitignore` I can *not* get git to ignore the `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` file below:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:  CalFoo.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/wcochran.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

I am using/editing the `.gitignore` file listed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects).
I tried everything to match the pattern including the exact pathname: `CalFoo.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/wcochran.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` to no avail.

This particular problem arises from the workflow where Xcode is used to create the initial git repo and the `.gitignore` file from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects) is added afterwards. A more general answer to ignoring previously tracked files in git can be found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git) (I guess I never found this post in my search since it didn't have "gitignore" in the title).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: @Unicornist not a duplicate -- i want a specific file removed and ignored *everywhere* whereas the other question wants certain files to not be tracked globally.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can only ignore unversioned files but that file is already known to git.

If you want git to track that file, there is no need to tell git to ignore it.

If you don't want git to track that file use `git rm` and your ignore rule will start working.

**Caution: `git rm` will remove the file.** Use `git rm --cached` to remove from the repo but not from the disk.

Comment: Caution, `git rm` will remove the file. Use `git rm --cached` to remove from the repo but not from the disk.

Comment: Thanks @michas and Darkhogg -- it is now not being tracked by get and is removed from the repo.

Comment: This answer corresponds to what I used to believe: but today, I have a file which is in .gitignore, it is not controlled, and it still shows up in "git status" as an untracked file (its filename is 'build').  No amount of "git rm build" or touching the .gitignore helps.  Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here w/ @Stabledog

Comment: @Stabledog @AllenLinatoc There are multiple possible ignore files, which might contain exclude rules. Try `git check-ignore` and maybe ask a new question to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 28):

I had same problem.

First commit any outstanding code changes, and then, run this command:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

This removes any changed files from the index(staging area), then just run:

```
git add .
```

Commit it:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore working now"
```

To undo git rm --cached filename, use git add filename.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had to add my list to the xcode source control Ignored Files.
setting -> source control -> git -> + in Ignored Files

[image: xcode git ignore]
For good measure make sure to reset so the new git rules work.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

Comment: I can't find where you started from...  I can't get to the screen you captured.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done something like `echo node_modules >> .gitignore`, it won't work.

The windows terminal saves the file in `UCS-2 LE BOM` and git doesn't seem to accept that.

You can open the file with `Notepad` and save it with `UTF-8` encoding

[image: notepad save utf-8 encoding]

**It Works now.**

I think they need to fix this since `echo "filetoignore" >> .gitignore` actually seems a handy thing to do

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I tried removing the cache, add, commit, push, etc... and nothing worked. Just doing this simple fix worked wonders.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways to ignore files on GitHub is perfectly explained here
https://help.github.com/en/articles/ignoring-files

**Before you do any push to GitHub, your project folder should be blank.**

1) open terminal and write **cd**

and drag your project folder over terminal. After that it will look like this:

```
docmacbook$ cd /Users/docmacbook/Downloads/MyProjectFolder
```

2) Open .gitignore file and add files you want to ignore. For example my .gitignore file looks like this:

```
MyAppName.xcodeproj/xcuserdata
MyAppName.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
Pods
report.xml
```

3) **Commit** and **Push** to GitHub.

After this move your project or create a new one in the folder where .gitignore file is and now files you want to be ignored will not be pushed to your GitHub.

Note: These steps will work for an existing project too I think, did not tested.