# Difference between "Keep Xcode Version" vs. "Use Version on Disk"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I use git, I usually change between branches and my `iOSBaseSDK.xcworkspace` file is modified.

When this happen my Xcode shows the following  alert:

[image]

> The file "YourProject.xcworkspace" has been modified by another application
>
> The file is located at "LOCATION". Do you want to keep the Xcode version, or use the version on disk?
>
> Keep Xcode Version
> Use Version on Disk

I don't understand the meaning of the two options, as they relate to the git branches I am switching between.

What is the difference between **Keep Xcode Version** and **Use Version on Disk**?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's have this assumption , suppose you have a file inside your xcode project and out of xcode you edited it without hitting save , then inside xcode you tried to edit that same file , then you'll get that message

**Xcode version :** the one you currently editing

**Disk version :** the stored version on disk

git changes the local files automatically and when the change is wide xcode shows that message , so after a git pull click **Use version on disk**