# Xcode 6: What to ignore when committing to SVN so the application can later be checked out and runnable without any extra work?

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I want to commit the minimum amount of files and still be able to checkout and have it working without ANY work. This will be specifically used for a Phonegap iOS application. However, any relation to iOS apps will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you may ignore only the `builds/` folder as the files in there are generated every build. Have been working in a project with other develops having only this folder `.gitignore`'d.

If you wish, you may [ignore several other files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021580/2752041) to make your repository as clean as possible.

Another way to commit as little as possible is to use external library managements, such as [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/). Just remember to ignore `Pods/` folder and run `pod install` when first running the project on a new computer.

Comment: I can say that deleting the build folder gave a couple errors. However, I did delete Hook's folder and WWW folder from under project root. Since the real app is placed in: appRoot/platforms/android/Assets/www, then the primary www folder is deletable.

Comment: @Itamar you're only supposed to **ignore** the `builds/` folder, not delete it completely. Nevertheless, this folder is re-created every time the project builds, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I understand the logic and process,  but if I commit everything except the builds/ folder, and I checkout on a different PC, I will not have the builds/ folder. When I run it following the checkout I get a missing file from builds/ folder error.

Comment: Maybe that's an Xcode 6 specific issue. It works fine like that in Xcode 7+.