# Does sourcetree automatically load .gitignore file?

Tags: gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

I create .gitignore file by textedit on mac.
( by following Adam of link [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects)    I create empty txt format file, and copy and paste it.)

And I put that file in .git folder in the project folder.

Then, Does sourcetree will 'automatically' load this .gitignore file as soon as I put the file in that folder ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it directly in the project folder not to .git. It will be automatically loaded by sourcetree from that folder