# How to synchronize Xcode settings (files/folders organization and build settings) with teammates?

Tags: xcode

I have an Xcode project and I'm working with a team.

I have re-organized the files and set all the correct settings to build properly. After that, I committed to the repo and asked my teammates to pull/update and continue working on it.

However, we found that the organization of files and build settings were not reflected in my teammates' computer when they opened the same project in Xcode.

I guess it is because Xcode saves each folder/file organization and settings specific to the user (in the xcuserdatad file?). So, how do I get my team's settings/preferences to be synchronized with mine? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for best practices, which is a little too close to opinion for Stack Overflow sometimes, but I think this could be regarded as best practice:
[Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects?rq=1)

In particular, if you are excluding from the repo any files beyond that list, that's what you should look at first.

Normally, the problem people are encountering is that things that are user-specific have made it into the repo, whereas what you're saying is that you feel there are things that are project-related that should be reflected on all the computers of all repo users, where you are not seeing this.

You likely need to be more specific about what you are and are not seeing synchronised on the two computers. For instance, if it is just whether a folder is in a collapsed or expanded state, I would definitely say that you should not want this to be synchronised over to other computers. You also mention about being able to build. If you cannot get the project to build, it is likely you may be having issues with provisioning profiles. What do the specific build error messages say?