# Git Ignore Basics

Tags: xcode, git, file, terminal, gitignore

I am very new to Git and am trying to use a .gitignore file. I have an Xcode project which includes many CocoaPods and Nodejs modules. I want all these files to be ignored, but I'm not sure how to create a .gitignore file and how to specify which files to ignore. Somebody please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simply copy a .gitignore file from [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/):

https://www.gitignore.io/api/xcode

Second, make sure those files were not *already* added to the index.
Do a `git check-ignore -v -- a/file/I/want/ignored`: if it returns nothing, then remove it from the index (`git rm --cached a/file/I/want/ignored`) and try again.