# npx command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npx

I am working with webpack and I need to execute `./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` using `npx`. `npx webpack` would run the webpack binary (`./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack`), but each time I execute npx webpack I get
`bash: npx: command not found`.

I am using:

- node: v9.5.0
- npm: 5.6.0
- nvm: 1.1.5
- webpack: 3.11.0

Comment: Did you install npx globally?

Comment: I was thinking npx command would be made available after webpack version 3.1.0 @omri

Comment: Thanks, npm v5.2.0 has the package incorporated @Omri

Answer (score 260, accepted):

npx should come with npm 5.2+, and you have node 5.6 .. I found that when I install node using nvm for Windows, it doesn't download npx.
so just install npx globally:

```
npm i -g npx
```

In **Linux** or **Mac** OS, if you found any permission related errors use sudo before it.

```
sudo npm i -g npx
```

Comment: when i try sudo npm i -g npx it says npm not found but npm by its own works?

Comment: @Jonathan most likely you need to `sudo apt-get install npm` first.

Answer (score 43):

if you are using Linux system, use `sudo` command

```
sudo npm i -g npx
```

Comment: windows ubuntu requires restarting the shell

Comment: For security reasons it's better to install global NPM packages without sudo.

Comment: Either way, I can't seem to get it running from the command line like the repository says. After having run `npm install -g npx`, typing in `npx` gives me the command not found. I'm running ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 16):

Remove NodeJs and npm in your system and reinstall it with the following commands:

**Uninstallation**

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
sudo apt remove npm
```

**Fresh Installation**

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

**Configuration** optional, in some cases users may face permission errors.

1. user defined directory where npm will install packages

   ```
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
2. configure npm

   ```
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
3. add directory to path

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
   ```
4. refresh path for the current session

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```
5. cross-check npm and node modules installed successfully in our system

   ```
   node -v
   npm -v
   ```

**Installation of `npx`**

```
sudo npm i -g npx
npx -v
```

Well done, we are ready to go. Now you can easily use `npx` anywhere in your system.

Comment: ` nodejs : Conflicts: npm`

Answer (score 4):

check versions of node, npm, npx as given below. if npx is not installed then use `npm i -g npx`

```
node -v
npm -v
npx -v
```

Comment: Like the original question says : "npx : command not found". npx is literally not there.

Comment: Because just like the original poster, I did download npm and I did install it. But, just like in the issue described, npx was "not there" (i.e. not found). The cause was some obscure Linux-related reason. To recap: When it says "command not found" then the issue is that command was not found. So "npx -v" will not work, and it's just reproducing the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using **macOS**, use **sudo** command

```
sudo npm install -g npx
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Either delete the path from user variable or correct the right path Restart CMD and it should work.**

```
 (C:\Program Files\nodejs).
```

Comment: closing the cmd and opening again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating node helped me, whether that be from the command line or just re-downloading it from the web

Answer (score 0):

I returned to a system after a while, and even though it had Node 12.x, there was no `npx` or even `npm` available. I had installed Node via `nvm`, so I removed it, reinstalled it and then installed the latest Node LTS. This got me both `npm` and `npx`.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install npm`
install npm first

(it will take around 177MB node also will get installed along with this cmd) space

Install npx
`sudo npm i -g npx`

Check the version of the installed npm,node,npx (for confirming latest release and installed or no it will show) using
`nod -v npx -v npm -v`

Answer (score 0):

**1. First step:**
check and install your node version with `node -v`.

**2. second step:**
check and install your npm version with `npm -v`.
If you still have a problem,might your command is `npx create_react_app your_app_name` instead of `npx create-react-app your_app_name`.

Answer (score 0):

check
node -v,npm -v, npx -v if are you getting output in the terminal but if you are executing these commands inside terminal of any IDE's like VSCODE, ATOM ... etc then reinstall that IDE.

Answer (score 0):

- I went to the documentation of vs-code (mentioned below on recourses section)
- Initially they ask to check the execution policy by executing `Get-ExecutionPolicy` on power shell of vs-code -> I got **Restricted**
- Next `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` to get all of the execution policies with their scorps. And I got the follwing result :/

> MachinePolicy       Undefined
> Process       Undefined
> CurrentUser       Undefined
> LocalMachine       Undefined

- Then I rechecked the error which was displayed at the beginning, in vs-code power shell

  'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the execution policy
  execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".
- In there too it's mentioned the err is about the current-user
- So I execute
  `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
- And it worked for me. It's pleasure if this would work to you too thanks.

Recourses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

Go To Program Files And Go to Nodejs folder. There will be a powershell file called npm and even npx
you can run all npm and npx commands in the respective powershells

Answer (score 0):

My issue may be completely unrelated but `npx` install was borked by my usage of `git worktree`.

**MY NICHE SOLUTION**

Remove the `git worktree`s you'd added. You can see them via `git worktree list` and then remove them with `git worktree remove <pathname>`

Answer (score -3):

try :

```
sudo su
```

then

```
npm i npx 
or 
npi i -g npx
```

check your npx version by

```
npx -v
```

Comment: I would recommend using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224061/19276480) instead as it achieves the same thing in a more secure way.