# npx not found, thought it is in the PATH

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm setting up a local environment for the React Tutorial and I'm having some issues.

What version of node do I have?

```
$ node -v
v10.10.0
```

Set up the tutorial environnment

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app
/opt/nodejs/bin/create-react-app -> /opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
+ create-react-app@1.5.2
added 67 packages from 20 contributors in 9.879s
```

Execute the instructions for tutorial setup:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
-bash: npx: command not found
```

What?! is npx missing?

```
$ npx 
-bash: npx: command not found
```

Hmm. Use this solution [(npx command not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894620/npx-command-not-working):

```
$ npm i -g npx
/opt/nodejs/bin/npx -> /opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npx/index.js
+ npx@10.2.0
added 484 packages from 651 contributors in 34.539s
```

It's installed? For sure?

```
$ whereis npx
npx: /opt/nodejs/bin/npx
```

Right. I don't trust you. What's in that directory?

```
$ v /opt/nodejs/bin/
total 34468
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kingram kingram       45 Sep 17 17:04 create-react-app -> ../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 35291184 Sep  6 13:15 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx       38 Sep  6 13:15 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx       32 Sep 17 17:10 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npx/index.js
```

Something looks wrong about that.

```
$ npx -v
-bash: npx: command not found
```

Back to the beginning. Maybe it's not built that way.

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
-bash: npx: command not found
```

I was right not to trust you.

So. Any thoughts from experienced users?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

NPM version

```
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

Where is npm?

```
$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
```

"...you should be able to execute create-react-app on its own without the npx prefix..."

```
$ create-react-app my-app    
-bash: create-react-app: command not found
```

Comment: Can you execute `which npm` and report the result?

Comment: Also, you _should_ be able to execute `create-react-app` on its own without the `npx` prefix

Comment: What is your `npm` version? You need [at least 5.2](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) to have `npx`

Comment: can you share your OS and version?

Comment: Can you check if `/usr/bin/npm` is a symlink to the one in `/opt`. It really just sounds like your `PATH` environment variable doesn't include `/opt/nodejs/bin/`. What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: Good call @Phil4 (lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Sep 14 16:21 /usr/bin/npm -> /etc/alternatives/npm)