# is react build for node 5.0.3

Tags: reactjs

npx command not found while creating react file

I am trying to create react app for node.js 5.0.3. But getting error for npx

npx create-react-app my-app

npx:command not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npx command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894620/npx-command-not-found)

Comment: npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

`npx` is part of `npm` and has been since version 5.2.0 which requires Node 4 or higher.

That said, Node 5.x is both a *development* branch and *ancient* so you really really shouldn't use it. Use [a supported version](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/).