# I am getting this error " 'npx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, "

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, npx

I am trying to do my first project in React.

However I am getting the following error from my terminal:

> 'npx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npx command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894620/npx-command-not-found)

Answer (score 7):

Install npx globally by running `npm i -g npx` in the terminal