# `npx create-nuxt-app <project name>` not working: MacOSX

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, package.json, macos-high-sierra, npx

I use a MacOS High Sierra. For anyone with experience with Nuxt.js, the command
`npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`  has not worked for me at all!

I consistently come across errors from `npm` saying I need to update my dependencies. I first tried updating each dependency using `npm outdated` (check for outdated packages) and
`npm update <pkg name>`. This did not work.

I also uninstalled and reinstalled `node` and `npm` and tired the above (and below processes). Still did not work.

No matter what I do, the Terminal keeps saying my `core-js` needed to be updated so I did that (I tried both `npm i core-js` and `npm i core-js` ) - they did not work.

To update the `npm` dependencies, I used the command `npm install -g npm-check-updates` followed by `ncu -u`, and then tried both `npm update` and `npm install`. Nothing has worked so far.

Lastly, I've tried creating a `package.json` since `npm` complained that I had no package.json so I created one using `npm init` and following the instructions to commit the file(s) created. Still, nothing after running `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`.

What is happening? Has anyone experienced this issue? I really love Nuxt.js and I've tried this for an entire day but I'm giving up on using NuxtJS.

**EDIT**: I managed to solve part of my problem by creating a Nuxt app from scratch. However, I get the following errors:

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nuxt-app@2.11.0 dev:`nuxt
`npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt-app@2.11.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue! It worked when I created a new directory altogether (the next day) and reran `npx create-nuxt-app <new-app>`. Get started, build for production, and tests ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solution based on your problem. Sharing a simple one, if you have npm installed then execute below command to install npx:

npm install -g npx

you can find all others solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894620/npx-command-not-found)

and My suggestions are:

As i saw your description, package.json not created. definitely something wrong for creation of the project, it may cause the read write problem of files into disk. or you have created the project into subdirectory but trying to run the project from parent directory. initially many peoples doing this practice to create scratch project. by the way create a separate directory and then run npx create-nuxt-app. no need to give project name and pass the phase when prompt to create project in same directory. so then i think problem will solved

Comment: I do have npx installed. I actually solved part of my problem by creating a Nuxt app from scratch but now when I run `npm run dev`, I get this error: `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nuxt-app@2.11.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt-app@2.11.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Comment: did you run npm install first?

Comment: yes, I did everything in the order I saw on Nuxt.js!

Comment: remove your npm modules, and install the packages by executing npm run install. then try again npm run dev

Comment: As i saw your description, package.json not created. definitely something wrong for creation of the project, it may cause the read write problem of files into disk. or you have created the project into subdirectory but trying to run the project from parent directory. initially many peoples doing this practice to create scratch project.

by the way create a separate directory and then run npx create-nuxt-app. no need to give project name and pass the phase when prompt to create project in same directory. so then i think problem will solved

Comment: Yes, thank you! Creating a separate directory and running the create-app command worked the next day (perfectly). For some reason, it didn't go so smooth the day before.

Comment: Thank you, as per discussion i changed the post,