# npx command not found. For reactJS

Tags: reactjs, npx

## I am trying to install `react-web`.

### Running the command

`npx create-react- app .`

It tells me

## `npx` command not found. This haven't happen earlier.

Then I run
`npx -v`

#### Again the same error:

**'npx command not found'**.

I decide to install npx. I run
`sudo npm i -g npx`
And this is what I get(refer the picture)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJVNR.png). How do I tackle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npx command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894620/npx-command-not-found)

Comment: what is your OS? And your npm version?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I did it finally.

Here are the steps I had to follow.

1. Open the terminal.
2. cd into `/usr/local/bin/`
3. ls the directory
4. Will find an npx file.
5. (remove this file)`sudo rm -i npx`
6. (re-install npx) `sudo npm i -g npx`
7. Done!

Hope it helps someone in need.