# the system cannot find the file npx create-react-app myapp

Tags: reactjs

To create a react app, when I use

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

I get an error saying

> "PS C:\Users\yashj\OneDrive\Desktop\messaging_app> npx create-react-app myapp
>   Program 'npx.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file
>   specifiedAt line:1 char:1
>   + npx create-react-app myapp
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + npx create-react-app myapp
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [],
>   ApplicationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed"

I have reinstalled nodejs again but still, I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe you have to try to reinstall or install npx globaly [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894620/npx-command-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224061/11285149)

Comment: One would think that at, what, node v11/12 it'd be sorted out. Check the above solution and manually install it, check it it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I suggest using the command in PowerShell
If the problem persists, install a new version of PowerShell and then run the command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).