# Flutter generated ios files version control

Tags: xcode, git, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that have been released to production several times, but last time I built I ran into some newly generated files out of `/ios/build/XCBuildData`, most of them named like `random-desc.xcbuild` or `random-manifest.xcbuild` and one `build.db` file.

I'm not sure why these files started showing up, but I can't seem to find information if they are to be checked in or ignored by .gitignore.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I tried removing them all and running `flutter clean`, but they all come back..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021580/5565834)
All the build folder should be ignored (including XCBuildData)